# Change state of Azure Form Recognizer selectionmark

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

For smart and automatic processing of simple forms with similar structure, I have set up a model in the online editor, manually tagging the fields that I need.

However, for some forms the selectionmark tag automatically reads 'unselected' when labelling, even though the checkbox is selected (although not very clearly sometimes). Does somebody know of a way to manually change the state of the selectionmark tag to 'selected' to make my model even smarter?

Answer (score 0):

Form Recognizer does not yet support manually changing the selection marks status or customization and training for the selection mark status. The above seems like a selection mark miss where Form Recognizer Layout did not recognize correctly the selection mark state. If you can share a snippet of the selection mark or contact Form Recognizer Contact Us formrecog_contact@microsoft.com we can look into this in details.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have gathered some snippets for you which I will make sure find their way to you!